# php code to get the timezone and the difference in current system time with GMT 

Tags: php, javascript

Please help me with the php code to get the timezone and the difference in current system time with the London time
I need to get the time zone from where the mail is sent.After that i need to get the current system time as well as the GMT difference of current system time in php

Comment: @Corbin:tried with php.net/datetimezone

Comment: Try this @Riya http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Comment: Tested method for the question can be accessible in [TimeZone Difference Between UTC and User TimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426029/how-to-manage-timezone-for-different-users-of-different-countries-for-a-php-web/55155690#55155690)

Comment: Tested method for the question can be accessible in [TimeZone Difference Between UTC and User TimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426029/how-to-manage-timezone-for-different-users-of-different-countries-for-a-php-web/55155690#55155690)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side, and calling `date()` will give the time of the server.

You can pass different arguments to `date()` to get the information you need. `date('Z')` will give you the timezone offset in seconds (offset from UTC/GMT). You can also get it in hours and minutes using `date('P')`.

To get the timezone of your local machine, you'll have to use something client-side, like Javascript. You could use [jsTimezoneDetect](http://www.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript) to do this.

Give Javascript access to the server date, and compare the two dates:

```
var server_date = new Date(<?= date("YYYY-MM-DD") ?>);
var local_date = new Date();
```

You'll need to replace `YYYY-MM-DD` with a more appropriate time-and-date format string.

Comment: can i get my current system time zone in php

Answer (score 1):

get the current system time zone offset
get the the london time zone offset(from mail is sent)
London time zone : date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

Comment: also can i get current system time as well as europe time in single page 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](http://ditio.net/2008/06/03/php-datetime-and-datetimezone-tutorial/) and [this PHP class](http://in.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) should be enough for your needs

Comment: I tried this code in localhost

<?php
echo date_default_timezone_get();echo'<br>';
echo date('H:i:s');echo'<br>';
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');echo'<br>';
echo date_default_timezone_get();echo'<br>';
echo date('H:i:s');echo'<br>';
?>
but I am getting 
UTC
07:39:16

GMT
07:39:16

Answer (score 0):

Tested function to get timezone difference between UTC and User's Timezone (Asia/Kolkata) can found 
[TimeZone Difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426029/how-to-manage-timezone-for-different-users-of-different-countries-for-a-php-web/55155690#55155690)