# How to manage timezone for different users of different countries for a php web application?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I am developing web application. The application has different users from different countries.

I have used to manage thier registrations using UTC timestamp. It works fine for me.

But problem occures when I am checking the expiry date of account.

**For example -**

Suppose registration will be valid for 15 days and user from India whose registration date is 11 June 2014 as per Asia/Kolkata timezone, in the database table I have stored the registration date in Unix Timestamp format (Server set to UTC timezone), on 16th day I want to expire his account and when I am executing query by compairing todays date (date in timestamp, date is converted to timestamp using strtotime() function of PHP), I found there is difference in One day.
How to handle these type of situation? This is not only registration problem but some other conditions also there.
Also if I want to send email of registration expiry using cron job, how it will works?

Comment: 15 days are 15 days regardless of timezone. If your server registered the user and recorded the timestamp of when it did so, it will also be able to identify when it's 15 days later. You'll have to show how exactly you're managing to get this wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this will works for registration scenario. But if user wants the report of some record within the provided date range by user then how to compare the dates in MYSQL query for that user timezone?

Comment: Basically: 1) Know what timezone the user is in (ask him), 2) know what timezone you're storing your data in (UTC is good, but anything works as long as it's consistent), 3) convert between the two timezones as needed.

Comment: It really depends on what you want.  Do you mean to expire at the exact time of registration after 15 calendar days have elapsed?  Or at the *end* of the 15th calendar day?  Or after 15 intervals of 24 hours (360 hours)?   Do you have the user's time zone stored separately in your database?  Also - keep in mind that not all days are 24 hours.  In time zones that have daylight saving time, transition days are 23 or 25 hours.  And in one time zone (`Australia/Lord_Howe`), they are 23.5 or 24.5 hours.

Comment: Showing some code would help here also.  It's not enough to just say that you use strtotime.  Please show us an example, and provide data values.  See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.  Thanks.

Comment: I found a solution but I am not sure its right or wrong. Suppose I will store all time as per UTC in database and at the time of registration of user I will take the timezone using javascript/jquery, store it in user table. When user logged in or for his account expiry we can show the dates as per his timezone. Also we can give him to change timezone in 'Edit Profile'.

Answer (score 0):

You need do few steps.

- Database table of all countries along their timezone
- On registration or form submit get IP address
- Check details based on IP and get Country and Timezone
- Save country and timezone along record information

In this way, you can maintain the records along their creator's timezone.

As far as expiring records based on timezone then you can check based on their timezone.

Suppose I am in Pakistan and timezone is 5+. So expiry step should also follow my timezone.

Comment: But I am not storing their countries in database, and I think maintaining database of IP, countries and timezone is not good. And user will not logged in from same IP address always.

Comment: Then you can make everything (expire things) based on server's timezone such as US or UK timezone.

Comment: Many countries have multiple time zones.  IP geolocation isn't always accurate, and time zones are more than just a single offset.  Sorry, but this is bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @function getusertimezonedifference return timezone difference with UTC
 * @param integer $timezonedifference       optional
 * @return string time
 * @Comment Get User TimeZone Difference
 */
public function getusertimezonedifference($timezone = "Asia/Kolkata", $changetoUTC=false, $flg_array=false)
{
    #$timezone = "Asia/Kolkata";+5.30
    #$timezone = "America/Anchorage";-9
    #$timezone = "America/Los_Angeles";-8
    #$timezone = "America/Dawson_Creek";-8
    #$timezone = "America/Chicago";-6
    #$timezone = "America/New_York";-5
    #$timezone = "America/Halifax";-4
    #$timezone = "America/St_Johns";#3.30
    $dayLightFlag = false;
    $system_timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    $local_timezone = "UTC";
    date_default_timezone_set($local_timezone);
    $local = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
    $gmt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
    $required = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    date_default_timezone_set($system_timezone);
    $diff1 = (strtotime($gmt) - strtotime($local));
    $diff2 = (strtotime($required) - strtotime($gmt));
    if($changetoUTC) {$diff2 =  (-1*$diff2);}
    // extract hours
    $hours = floor($diff2 / (60 * 60));
    // extract minutes
    $divisor_for_minutes = $diff2 % (60 * 60);
    $minutes = floor($divisor_for_minutes / 60);
    // extract the remaining seconds
    $divisor_for_seconds = $divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    $seconds = ceil($divisor_for_seconds);

    //create string HH:MM:SS
    $ret = $hours.":".(($minutes>9)?$minutes:"0$minutes").":".(($seconds>9)?$seconds:"0$seconds");
    if($flg_array){$ret = array($hours, ((abs($minutes)>9)?$minutes:"0$minutes"), ($seconds>9)?$seconds:"0$seconds");}
    return ($ret);
}
```